# IOS Making Storyboards Quicker

Tags: ios, storyboard, psd, fireworks

I've a more experienced ios developer so I'm simply trying to streamline the storyboard creation process. I'm not a big UI guy and I'd rather be in the code than interface builder.

Does anyone know of a solution out there that can expedite this process?

I've looked at app creators like appcelerator an mosync but their just not flexible enough for the projects I've been getting in lately. I get mostly fireworks designs but sometimes I outsource some imaging for PSDs if that helps. Any suggests?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Runtime performance or workflow?

Comment: So pretty much I get a fireworks png from my UI guy. I get my image slices, create a new project in Xcode and then start creating my UI in interface builder importing my image files and getting them all set up to match exactly whats in the design. Is there a tool out there that you know of that can speed this process up?

Comment: Not really. That is pretty much the workflow I have also.